# Administrator: Windows PowerShell Set-Service yields Access is denied, but sc.exe config works fine

Tags: windows, powershell, service

I'm trying to convert a script that was using a mixture of PowerShell and native Windows executables (such as `net.exe`, `sc.exe`) to using exclusively PowerShell commands as it seemed like that would be straightforward to do, make the script more consistent, and allow for idempotency.

Well, I'm running into an issue. In the previous version of the script, it would do the following:

```
sc.exe config "LxssManager" type= auto
```

Which would set the `LxssManager` service to a startup type of `Automatic`. Cool.

However, when changing it over to use native PowerShell cmdlets, it looks as such:

```
Set-Service -Name "LxssManager" -StartupType Automatic
# Same results with...
# Get-Service -Name "LxssManager" | Set-Service -StartupType Automatic
```

Great.

In both iterations of the script, administrative permissions are required, as it involves enabling/disabling services; all of the following commands are run using an elevated/Administrator PowerShell terminal/session. However, I'm running into an issue where the previous version using `sc.exe` works, where the new PowerShell version (`Set-Service`) fails with the following error:

```
Set-Service : Service 'LxssManager (LxssManager)' description cannot be configured due to the following error: Access is denied
At line:1 char:35
+ Get-Service -Name "LxssManager" | Set-Service -StartupType Automatic
+                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Set-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotSetServiceDescription,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetServiceCommand
```

In that same PowerShell session though, I can do the following with no issue:

```
> sc.exe config "LxssManager" start= auto
[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS
```

I don't understand how in the same context, doing what should more or less be the exact same action I can get an access denied error, and also have it succeed.

I isolated the error in the script down to this one line, but I'm not sure what else to do at this point. I tried searching around SO/Google for anyone running into this same issue—but nobody seemed to have this situation exactly happening for them, so I'm a bit lost. Any advice would be quite helpful, thanks!

#### Environment data

##### PowerShell

```
$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.22621.2428
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.22621.2428
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

##### OS Info

```
Microsoft Windows 11 Enterprise Version 10.0.22621 Build 22621, x64-based
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: This isn't a complete explanation, and the workarounds offered may or may not work for you; all commands below assume execution from an *elevated* (run as admin) session:

- I see the symptom on my Windows 11 22H2 machine as well.
- `sc.exe config "LxssManager" start=auto` works *only* with a `auto` as the `start=` value - any other value causes an access-denied error too.

  - Ditto with [`Set-Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-service), which, however - despite *succeeding* with value `Automatic` - reports a *spurious error*. (All other startup types cause *true* access-denied errors, as with `sc.exe`)
- *Interactively*, via `services.msc`, trying to change to *any* different startup type (including `Automatic`) results in a (genuine) access-denied error.
- Curiously, there's nothing obvious in the *permissions* associated with the underlying registry key, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LxssManager`, and checking the effective access for the `Administrators` group indicates *full access*.

  - Equally curiously, directly modifying the registry value that determines the start-up type, `Start`, *is* permitted.

Generally, it's worth noting that some services have permissions configured that deny even *read* access via [`Get-Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service) to administrators in elevated sessions.

---

**Workarounds**:

Note: I'm unclear on whether other services are affected too; the workarounds focus just on the `LsxxManager` service.

- If setting the startup type to `Automatic` is the only modification of the `LsxxManager` service that you need, you can simply *ignore* the spurious error that `Set-Service` reports, as long as you have ensured that your script runs *with elevation* (as administrator) in principle.
- If you need to set a *different* startup type, modify the underlying registry definition directly.

  - Note: I'm unclear on whether the service manager picks up on such changes dynamically or whether a logoff / reboot is required.
  - The possible values for the `Start` registry value are: `0` (Boot), `1` (System), `2` (Automatic), `3` (Manual, aka demand to `sc.exe`), `4` (Disabled), per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicestartmode)
  - E.g., the following command sets the startup type to `4` (Disabled):

    ```bash
    # Requires elevation
    Set-ItemProperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LxssManager Start 4
    ```

Comment: That's particularly interesting that the error has no bearing on whether the command actually succeeded or not.

Thanks for this write-up, it's quite helpful. I'm not sure it completely answers the question so much as provides workarounds and some further investigation so I'm not going to mark it as the accepted answer quite yet.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @johhnytex; if you solve the mystery completely, do tell, so I can update the answer or post an answer of your own.